# Git Terminal in Android Studio Character PRoblem

Tags: android, bash, git, android-studio, terminal

I've faced with an issue when i updated the Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1.
Before the update i could write "~" character with git bash on Android Studio but after the update i can't use '~' and '`' characters at all. It prints nothing on the console. These characters works fine in other fields but git bash.